# Django IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed with NULLABLE field

Tags: django, django-models

When trying to create a superuser in Django, I'm getting the error:
`django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: b3ack_investoruser.watchlist`

I have a custom user and, the only custom field IS NULLABLE:

```
class InvestorUser(AbstractUser):
    id          = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    watchlist   = models.JSONField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)
```

**manage.py has:**

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'b3ack.InvestorUser'
```

**admin.py has:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import InvestorUser

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(InvestorUser)
```

I have tried
`python3 manage.py sqlflush`

I have redone all my migrations.
I have deleted previous migrations.

None of that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps:

```
1 - Delete migrations Folder
2 - Delete db.sqlite3 (delete database)
3 - run command (python manage.py makemigrations your_app_name)
4 - run command (python manage.py migrate)
```